# como mostrar imagen subida a servidor tomcat con etiqueta html img

Tags: tomcat

Tras subir las imágenes al servidor no consigo la forma de mostrarla mediante una etiqueta html. ¿Cual es la ruta del servidor?

El tema es que no tengo muy claro en qué ubicación guardarla para posteriormente poder acceder a ella y mostrarla mediante una etiqueta html de imagen. En mi aplicación mediante un formulario creo una ficha para registrar un rosal y uno de sus campos es tipo file para subir una foto de la rosa. Subo la imagen y la almaceno en mysql mediante una campo de tipo blob. Más adelante, si un usuario quiere ver la imagen pues la recupero de la base de datos y es ahi donde no tengo claro la ubicación donde almacenarla para poder mostrarla mediante la etiqueta html.

Comment: ¿qué haces con la imagen tras _subirla al servidor_?

Comment: ¿Qué ruta te imprime en la etiqueta img? Dinos cual es, a pesar de que no se muestre en el navegador.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu sitio es www.sitio.com y las imágenes están en el directorio *img* dentro del raiz del sitio, solo tienes que poner

```
<img src="img/imagen1.jpg">
```

Siempre pon la ruta relativa desde donde se esté ejecutando tu página